# Could not find main class

Tags: java, jar, manifest

Okay, so I've been trying to make and executable jar file. It runs with the command "java -jar bybys.jar", but when i try to run it with enter it gives me an error "Could not find the main class bardejov.Image. Program will exit."

Here's the manifest :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_02 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: bardejov.Image
```

(yes i used a new line)

When compiling the jar file I tried every possible combination with the directory, I don't know where the problem is. I used - `C:\Java\2D>jar cfm bybys.jar Manifest.txt bardejov/Image.class bardejov/Board.class  bardejov/*jpg`

The directory is:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
bardejov/Image.class
bardejov/Board.class
bardejov/siknius.jpg
```

And the main class:

```
package bardejov;

import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Image extends JFrame {

public Image() {

    add(new Board());

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(477, 530);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Siknius");
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Image();
}
}
```

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

I fixed it. The problem was I didin't have the newest JRE installed.

Comment: Did you make sure to configure your JAVA_HOME and PATH environment variables correctly?  I get this error if I don't include the ".;" in my JAVA_HOME variable so the compiler knows to check the current directory your compiling from for necessary files.

Comment: ??? Running a jar file (1) doesn't require JAVA_HOME -- none of the JDK tools use it for anything; and (2) doesn't involve a compiler.

Comment: Does is work if you do a `java -cp bybys.jar bardejov.Image`?

Answer (score 3):

There's an extra space character after the name fof the class in your Manifest.txt. This is hinted by the error message:

```
Could not find the main class bardejov.Image .
                                            ^^
```

Comment: this could be, I see the space in the Manifext excerpt (just highlight the text) but I don't see it before the . in the error message.

Comment: I suspect the OP typed the error message instead of copying and pasting. Copying from `cmd.exe` is not as easy as it could be.

Comment: My manifest is - "Main-Class: bardejov.Image" without the space

Comment: @Reus did you make sure, that the manifest in the jar file (not the Manifext.txt) is correct in every way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually appears to be that the jar doesn't contain an entry for the directory `bardejov`; it contains only entries for the files *in* the directory. You can see this in your listing; see how there's an entry for `bardejov`. When you create the jar file, you have to tell `jar` to include the directory, not just the files in it:

```
jar cfm bybys.jar Manifest.txt bardejov
```

Comment: Just did that, and I still get the error. Jar contents :

META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
bardejov/
bardejov/Board.class
bardejov/Board.java
bardejov/Image.class
bardejov/Image.java
bardejov/siknius.jpg

Comment: It's possible you had *both* this problem and the space-after-the-class-name problem. Did you edit the manifest.mf template file and make sure there's no space there?

Comment: There's a double new line in the MANIFEST.MF is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As from Java 6 you can specify an entry point with the jar command. The following command should create an executable jar file for your application:

```
jar cfe bybys.jar bardejov.Image bardejov/Image.class bardejov/Board.class bardejov/*jpg
```

You don't need to write and add a custom manifest.

Resource

- [Setting an Application's Entry Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

**Update**

The following works on my machine:

create a java source file at `example/Hello.java`:

```
package example;
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
  }
}
```

compile with command

```
javac example/Hello.java
```

jar with command

```
jar cfe example.jar example.Hello example/*.class
```

execute with command

```
java -jar example.jar
```

The output is

```
Hello world!
```

**Update2**

Now it looks like a configuration issue. The code and the jar are obviously correct.

For a quick fix/workaroud: Instead starting the jar directly, write a short batch or shell script file that simply executes the `java -jar ...` command.

Comment: *Now* it's time to have a look at your class files. Recompile and/or test the jar command with a simple HelloWorld application.

Comment: Tried a simple swing helloworld code, everything's the same even the error.

Comment: Yes it works, but so does my code if I run it from cmd. I want an executable which I can run with enter.

Comment: *sigh* - so it always worked fine (from a java/jar perspective) but not when you press "Enter" - like from the windows explorer?

Comment: yup, I've lost all hope by now

Answer (score -3):

open cmd prompt and type

```
set JAVA_HOME=c:\PATH\TO\JAVA_DIRECTORY
set CLASSPATH=.;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\lib
```

make sure to include these variables in your PATH environment variable, as well.

You can get to environment variables in Win7 by going to Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables.

Comment: *Terrible* advice about CLASSPATH; the best setting is to not have it set at all.

Comment: I beg to differ. Including "bin" or "lib" in the CLASSPATH is *never* appropriate -- it's the sort of thing newbies do when wildly flailing around in the dark. And the default -- no CLASSPATH at all -- is as if it were ".". So this adds nothing. Further, it's clear that java is on his path, or he wouldn't be able to get to the point he has.

Comment: Yes, some of us here are actually Java newbies.  It's a good way to learn by trying to help each other.  Once in a while mistakes are made.  I appreciate you taking the time to educate me.  Best wishes.